# Есть ли в PyCharm менеджер переменных, как в Spyder?

Tags: python, pycharm

В `IDE Spyder` есть менеджер переменных, в котором можно просмотреть созданные `dataframe` и значения переменных.
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли подобный функционал в `PyCharm`?

Comment: не легче скачать и посмотреть?

Answer (score 1):

Да, есть подобное
Запустите `Tools --> Python Console`.
В открытой консоли есть `Show Variables`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Вы это имеете ввиду?]

Если вы это имеете ввиду, то это появляется в режиме отладки (Debug) на любой точке останова (Breake Point) которую Вы установите в коде или при возникновении исключения (если код запущен в режиме отладки). Здесь же справа будут появляться ссылки для просмотра датафреймов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]